# Cannot ping Cisco Aironet 1130AG after rebooting Cisco 1941W

Tags: cisco

Okay I am currently setting up a Cisco 1941W and a Cisco 1130AG access point, The Access point is plugged directly into the 1941W `Ge 0/1`

I have configured them both so far that everything works fine I can connect to the 1130 or the 1941 just fine until I reboot the 1941W at that point after the reboot I can no longer ping the access point and any wireless clients using the access point do not get access to the network no matter how long I wait, Wireless clients can still ping the access poing but no more.

To get network access running again for clients connecting to the 1130 I have to unplug the access point from the 1941 `Ge 0/1` and then replug it in at that point network access is returned to all access point clients. Please see below diagnostics. I am still learning Cisco kit and assume that there is command that can fix this but my google fu is failing me. Can anyone shed any light on why unplugging and replugging the access point back in my fix the problem. I will add that at all times the `Ge 0/1` interface shows that its up.

```
router#ping 192.168.1.11
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.11, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/4 ms
!
!REBOOT ROUTER
!
router#ping 192.168.1.11
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.11, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
!
!Unplug wireless access point ethernet cable
!
*Aug  7 08:48:07.911: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down
*Aug  7 08:48:08.911: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down
!
!Replug wireless access point ethernet cable
!
*Aug  7 08:49:02.911: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up
*Aug  7 08:49:03.911: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up
!
!Ping again
!
router#ping 192.168.1.11
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.11, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/4 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling auto-negotiation for speed/duplex.

Best bet would be to set speed to 100 and duplex to full on both devices for the ports that connect them together.

ie:

```
conf t
int gig 0/1
speed 100
duplex full
```

Comment: Cheers I'll try this tomorrow im off site right now.